# Prototype as "just a plain object"

Tags: javascript

I always thought that a `prototype` had some magic around it, but it seems that a prototype is actually just an object attached to a function. As an example:

```js
function someMethod() {};

function Person(name) {
    Object.assign(this, {name});
}
Person.prototype.number = 4;
Person.prototype.letter = "a";
Person.prototype.method = someMethod;

let obj = {
    number:4, 
    letter:'a',
    method: someMethod
};

console.log(`\
${Object.entries(Person.prototype).toString()}
${Object.entries(obj).toString()}
${Object.entries(Person.prototype).toString() == Object.entries(obj).toString()}\
`);
```

Is that more or less a correct understanding of what the prototype is? Or does any other machinery go on behind the scenes that the `obj` in the above example does not include?

Comment: A prototype object is indeed just a plain object.

Comment: *"I always thought that..."*: what is your source? Did you know you can assign an object of your choice to a constructor's `prototype` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.prototype` object is indeed just an ordinary object. It is used in prototype chains like any other object can be used in them.

The only "magic" behind implicitly created `.prototype` objects on `function`s is that they have a non-enumerable `.constructor` property that points back to the function.

```js
function Person() {}
let obj = {};

console.log(Object.hasOwn(obj, 'constructor'));
console.log(Object.hasOwn(Person.prototype, 'constructor'));
```